# css div width according to image width

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div style="position: relative">
    <img src="http://52.66.90.164/Show_barcode">
    <div stule="position: absolute;top:100%;">
        <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%">Hello world my name is Rushabh Shah.</p>
        <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%">Hello world my name is Rushabh Shah.</p>
        <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%">Hello world my name is Rushabh Shah.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want 33.33% of image not parent div. How can I achieve this? Image width and height is dynamic.

Comment: take img tag inside `div` and give div width equals to image width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only possible if you can set `float: left;` on the image container `div` like following:

```html
<div style="position:relative; float:left;">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/650x150">
    <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; left:0; top:100%;">
        <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%">Hello world my name is Rushabh Shah.</p>
        <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%">Hello world my name is Rushabh Shah.</p>
        <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%">Hello world my name is Rushabh Shah.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing bro. Happy Ramadan.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below:

took img tag inside div and gave images width to div

```html
<div style="position: relative">
    
    <div style="position: absolute;top:100%;width:285px">
        <img src="http://52.66.90.164/Show_barcode" style="display:block">
        <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%">Hello world my name is Rushabh Shah.</p>
        <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%">Hello world my name is Rushabh Shah.</p>
        <p style="float:left;width: 33.33%">Hello world my name is Rushabh Shah.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Image width and height is dynamic.` . This eliminates the requirement

Comment: in this case add `width:100%` to `img` tag

Comment: else calculate images `width` using javascript/jquery and add this with to `div` tag

Comment: please post question with all requiment we can not guess what you do!

Comment: @user1608841 i think there is no way around using javascript here.

Comment: @zeropublix if you cannot use js and if you only wants css solution then my answer holds true.

Comment: @zeropublix you need to specify width of image equals to width of div !

Comment: @user1608841 I'm not the person asking the question, please refer to the actual person asking. I was just trying to help

Comment: @zeropublix ok... owner of the question then needs to use js in this case to calculate image with.. he doesn't mention anywhere that he cannot use javascript/jquery.